# How do I remove the default value upon submission in an unrequired input field if the value isn't changed?

Tags: javascript, html, input

By default, I have a value for an input field that tells the user what to put there (e.g. Enter your account number). I have a script on it that hides the value when you click on it and it reappears when you click away.

The field is not required though. If a user doesn't enter information into the field, the default value gets sent and causes an error because it allows numerical digits only. How can this default value be changed to nothing if the user doesn't fill in his account number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate your input before form post like this:

*Markup:*

```
<input type="text" id="txtAcc" name="txtAcc" value="Enter your account number..." />
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" onclick="validate();" value="Submit" />
```

*Javascript:*

```
// Validate input before form post
function validate(){
    var txtAcc = document.getElementById("txtAcc");
    var accNum = parseInt(txtAcc.value);
    if (!accNum || txtAcc.value == "Enter your account number..."){
        // Set default Account number
        txtAcc.value = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use default values. Use **[placeholders](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#The_placeholder_attribute)**.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Real Name">
```

**[Works in all decent browsers.](http://jsfiddle.net/kmwN6/)**

---

Alternatively, just ignore these values on the server side:

```
if ($_POST["realname"] == "Real Name") { real_name_not_provided(); }
```

---

If you still insist on using JavaScript (for better browser support), you can use something like the following:

```
 $(function() {
    if(!$.support.placeholder) { 
        var active = document.activeElement;
        $(':text').focus(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
                $(this).val('').removeClass('hasPlaceholder');
            }
        }).blur(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {
                $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('hasPlaceholder');
            }
        });
        $(':text').blur();
        $(active).focus();
        $('form').submit(function () {
            $(this).find('.hasPlaceholder').each(function() { $(this).val(''); });
        });
    }
});
```

**[Taken from this article (which was first on Google by the way)](http://www.cssnewbie.com/cross-browser-support-for-html5-placeholder-text-in-forms/)**. Please read the article before using this code. It might require more code from the article.

Comment: What is an option that will work in IE7 and above? I don't have access to place anything server-side.

Comment: Use placeholder in conjunction with feature detection (ie. http://modernizr.com/). Then if the browser doesn't support placeholders, use JavaScript to remove the text. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the HTML5 [placeholder attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#The_placeholder_attribute) on browsers that support it.

The real answer is why is the validation code not smart enough to ignore the default text?